# Android sdk does not show x86 system images as an option to download

Tags: android

In the Android SDK I am not seeing and option to download the x86 system images. When I view the 'SDK Update Sites' tab, all the urls to system images, such as https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon.xml, have a red exclamation point indicating it failed to fetch from the URL. Are there new urls I can put in or another way to download the x86 system images?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Android studio http proxy]

Check if you have correctly configured proxy settings in android studio

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue. The Url for x86 System Images is invalid.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used http://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml, (http instead of https), then was able to download the system images. Funny it just started acting up today.